# Preguntas y respuestas anidadas en Laravel

Tags: laravel-blade, laravel-6

estoy con un proyecto que maneja productos que son publicados por los usuarios. Los productos permiten que otros usuarios hagan preguntas por los productos, y el autor de la publicación puede responder. El problema lo tengo en la parte de los comentarios.

---

En la tabla comentarios tiene un campo id, user_id (el que crea la pregunta), parent_id (sería un campo donde almaceno la "respuesta" y que sería el id de la pregunta de la misma tabla) y el body. Hay otros campos que no interesarían exponer. La cuestión es que para llevar a la vista los comentarios que tiene la publicación hago `$comments = Comment::orderBy('parent_id')->get();` Resulta que si hago esa consulta en la BD, y me devuelve: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Despues Laravel hace esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

osea que el orden que le exijo no lo toma en cuenta y me devuelve ordenados por id... cómo puedo resolver esto ?

```
@foreach($product->comments as $comment)
            @if($comment->id === $comment->parent_id)

            <li class="media mb-3 pos-relative">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="/images/users/{{ $comment->user->profile->image }}" alt="{{ $comment->user->name }}" class="d-flex mr-3 img-thumbnail img-fluid" style="width:50px; height:50px; border-radius:50%">
                </a>


                <div class="media-body">
                    <ul class="list-inline blog-meta text-muted">
                        <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> <a href="#">{{ $comment->user->name }}</a></li>
                        <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> {{ $comment->created_at }}</li>
                    </ul>
                    <p>{{ $comment->body }}</p>
                    @auth
                        @if($product->user_id === Auth::user()->id && $comment->user_id != Auth::user()->id) 
                        <p>
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#comment{{ $comment->uuid }}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="comment{{ $comment->uuid }}">
                                Responder
                            </button>
                        </p>
                        <div class="collapse" id="comment{{ $comment->uuid }}">
                            <div class="card card-body">
                                {!! Form::open(['route' => 'replyProducts']) !!}
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        {{ Form::text('id', $product->id , ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'id', 'hidden']) }}
                                        {{ Form::text('parent_id', $comment->id , ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'parent_id']) }}
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        {{ Form::textarea('body', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'comment', 'rows' => '4', 'onKeyDown' => 'valida_longitud()', 'onkeyup' => 'valida_longitud()', 'onpaste' => 'return false']) }}
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        {{ Form::submit ('Responder', ['class' => 'btn btn-success btn-lg float-right']) }}
                                    </div>
                                {!! Form::close() !!}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    @endif

                    @endauth
                </div>
            </li>
            @else
                <li class="media mb-3 pos-relative ml-5">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="/images/users/{{ $comment->user->profile->image }}" alt="{{ $comment->user->name }}" class="d-flex mr-3 img-thumbnail img-fluid" style="width:50px; height:50px; border-radius:50%">
                    </a>
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <ul class="list-inline blog-meta text-muted">
                            <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> <a href="#">{{ $comment->user->name }}</a></li>
                            <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> {{ $comment->created_at }}</li>
                        </ul>
                        <p>{{ $comment->body }}</p>
                    </div>
                </li>
            @endif
        @endforeach
```

dentro de un foreach primero consulto si el id del comentario es igual al parent_id. Si son iguales, se trata de una pregunta. Si difiere el id del comentario y el parent_id, se trata de una respuesta y lo unico que hago es indentar la respuesta.

```
Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->uuid('uuid')->unique()->nullable()->index();

        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');

        $table->unsignedBigInteger('parent_id')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('comments')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');

        $table->string('body');
        $table->morphs('commentable');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

esa es la tabla comments

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el resultado que envía el controlador a la vista está bien... no entiendo por que se modifica en la vista...

Comment: aja y el codigo?

Comment: recorro con un foreach los comments pasados desde el controlador... nada de otro mundo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luego de mucho andar y de andar solicitando ayuda por diversas partes, llegue al resultado. El tema es que en el modelo de productos (Product) y su relación con los comentarios, tenía que poner dentro de esa relación, el campo sobre el cual quería que se haga el criterio de ordenamiento.
Queda una cosa asi:

---

```
public function comments(){
    return $this->morphMany(Comment::class, 'commentable')->orderBy('parent_id', 'asc');
    // uno a muchos polimorfico
}
```

---

El resultado es esta belleza

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ASUNTO RESUELTO

Comment: Si esto dio solución a tu duda, por favor no olvides marcarla como aceptada, de modo que